# Object changes not rendering

Tags: rendering

Rendered an image, rendered an animation (without Suzanne), now when I add Suzanne to my scene, she is not visible in any render.  I must be doing something wrong by can't figure out what.

See image, as you can see Suzanne shows up in my layout and in layout render mode but NOT in the render.  I can't figure out why.

[image]

Comment: Did you re-render? The rendered image in the smaller window doesn't seem to match up with the camera angle in the viewport.

Comment: Yes, I've rerendered multiple times.  I've restarted blender and rerendered.    It does appear that the render image is cached but I can't seem to find any adjustments that resolve this

Comment: Is there anything in the VSE?

Comment: yes, as I had first generated my pngs, then used vse to animate.  It's almost as if when I switched my output back to png and rerendered, it's taking the right amount of tine to render but what appears looks like the old render, as if those first renders are cached

Comment: That must be it. Try unchecking the Sequencer box in the Post Processing tab at the bottom of Output Properties.

Comment: BINGO!  Thanks @HISEROD.  I seem to recall running into something similar a long time ago but it's been ages since I done animation.  Very unintuitive, the sequencer tooltip says that it will run the rendered (and composited) output thru the sequence editor pipeline.  That does not really clarify why that setting impacts PNG render after switching back from doing an animation.  That feels like a bug.  Is there any reason why it would behave that way?

Comment: It's not really a bug. Blender just grabs whatever is in the VSE if any strips have been added. Although, it is definitely an oddity. I'm guessing from the tooltip (and from previous experience iirc) that whatever is in the VSE basically gets treated as the render output from the camera and hence, is ran through any compositor nodes that you may have.

Comment: Nope, that was wrong. It doesn't get run through the compositor once it's in the VSE. Although, there might be a way to do it.